# New created table placed in additional file

Tags: sql-server, file, location

I want to store every new created table in an additional file located in the folder "C:\data\".

I think this has something to do with a `model database`, but I have less clearity on that. Can anybody suggest me a way to achieve this?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is to create a FileGroup, and set that FileGroup as the default

```
ALTER DATABASE  [dscat] 
ADD FileGroup [MyDataGroup] 
ALTER DATABASE [dscat] 
ADD FILE 
    ( NAME = test1dat3,
    FILENAME = 'c:\temp\dscat_target_for_tables.ndf',
    SIZE = 5MB,
    MAXSIZE = 100MB,
    FILEGROWTH = 5MB)
TO FILEGROUP  [MyDataGroup] 

ALTER DATABASE [dscat] 
MODIFY FILEGROUP [MyDataGroup] DEFAULT
```

Then a simple `CREATE TABLE` will use the new default filegroup

```
CREATE TABLE TEST (kf INT primary key , df varchar(99))
```

where-as you can target a specific FileGroup (such as PRIMARY) with the ON keyword:

```
CREATE TABLE MyUsers (kf INT primary key , df varchar(99)) ON  [PRIMARY]
```

REF
a) https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174979.aspx
b) https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa275464(v=sql.80).aspx

Comment: BTW, use of the `.NDF` file type for an secondary `.MDF` is optional.  You can use .MDF if you prefer.   If you apply a similar technique to the MODEL database, you have to recreate your database afterwards.